# Why would blog article views drop after major improvements?

Tags: traffic, landing-page

We recently made the following improvements to an article in French titled "Mots et expressions pour parler québécois"
1. The word count increased from 1333 to 2040
2. Improvements were essentially adding words and expressions, thereby increasing the usefulness of the page for our readers. So no SEO monkey business.
3. We marginally increased the keyword density of some words like "québécois", "mots" and "expressions" but the highest density is 1.37% which seems quite reasonable. I often find that keyword densities of high ranking pages in my domain regularly exceed 2.5%. So I don't suspect google flagged us for keyword stuffing of over-optimization.

Despite these improvements, traffic dropped as a percentage of total page views from 12.54% to 11.66% after 3 weeks.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Adding to the answers that mention the short timeframe: the changes you did are not really what you should be doing to improve your content; "adding words and expressions" is definitely not enough to increase a page usefulness. Also, keyword density is a very, VERY outdated concept in SEO and in 2020 you shouldn't be worrying about this at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three weeks and less than a 1% variance?  You may want to give it longer before you assume you did something wrong.

I suspect, but have no proof, that Google's algorithm has a randomizing feature that moves similar articles up and down the SERP results to test which articles users respond better to.

To add to the complexity, Google's algorithm is updated frequently, while it may re-index content infrequently, even if you've submitted it via GSC.

Given that, it's hard to know if Google's index is using the old version or the new version of your page in your ranking.  I'd give it a few more weeks to see if things change.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as the other writer says, it's too early to panic. Google works in mysterious ways and the drop is hardly anything to cry about. I suspect your site will go back to where it was in a little while.